# USB DAC with Parametric EQ?

Tags: usb, audio, signal-processing

For a while now, I've had a 10-band graphic EQ as an ALSA output device on a Raspberry Pi (https://scribles.net/enabling-equalizer-on-raspberry-pi-using-alsa-equal-plugin/), to try and correct my speakers' overexuberant and almost-painful midrange.  It works, but it also seems to corrupt the sound a little bit in addition to the desired effect.  Like it can't quite keep up, and frequently drops enough samples to hear the glitches.

I really wanted a parametric EQ, since it only takes one or maybe two bands of that to do what's really needed, but I didn't find any in an easy-to-add format.  And I don't think it would fix the glitches.

So I want to offload that processing to another device.  I thought about creating a one- or two-band analog PEQ circuit, since my speakers only have an analog input anyway, but if I can put that function *before* the DAC, I think it would be even better.  Is there such a thing?:

- USB stereo "sound card", nothing fancy on that front
- Full-parametric EQ as a DSP function
- Stereo DAC

I suspect that it would be a USB composite device between the obvious audio interface, and USB-HID or -MIDI for detailed settings, but not necessarily.  However it works is fine with me, as long as it works with a Pi.

Comment: Maybe this can fit the bill. It says it's supported by Alsa at least: https://www.minidsp.com/products/plate-amplifiers/il-dsp-headphone-amp  Has a parametric EQ that can be easily disabled.

Comment: @NatsuKage It also says that the control app only works on Mac and Windows.  Not Linux.  Otherwise, it looks nice.  (I guess I could jerry-rig a Windows box to it and set it that way, then plug it back into the Pi, but that's kinda clunky.)

Comment: You could also just make a quick VM of windows on Linux and control the app from there. I agree its not ideal... Fits the bill I think though once programmed. Not exactly cheap, though its fine for the price range.

Comment: Why not go for an analog solution? I used a 40-years old EQ on the line between my PC and the amp (no eq loop unfortunately :/) and it worked decently.

Comment: @JanDorniak Yes, I could do that, and I haven't completely discounted the idea.  It would need to be a custom design because of the physical space, but I can do that.  But then there's the cost of making a custom one-off device, compared to an off-the-shelf thing that does far more.

Comment: And from a technical standpoint, DSP is lightyears better quality than analog.  Yes, analog can have a "character" that people like, but that's technically distortion, which I'm not interested in for this application.  Quantized time in digital is a misconception, and quantized amplitude is far lower than an analog noise floor.  (https://www.xiph.org/video/vid2.shtml)

Comment: @AaronD if you're up for it, Audio Weaver, a DSP code generator, has a free version for STM32 devices. People have used STM32F4 Discovery as a DAC successfully. All you need is to create your effect from blocks in Audio Weaver. Requires a Windows PC

Comment: @JanDorniak Hmm...seemingly equivalent functionality in a slightly larger size than the MiniDSP but not obtrusively large, for 1/4 the cost.  ($25 compared to $100)  That could be attractive.  Windows only is still a bummer, but if it remembers the settings and the audio *stream* works on a Pi, then it's no worse than the MiniDSP.

Comment: @AaronD basically, you build your effect/EQ/whatever out of blocks and it's programmed into the board. You can even test it almost live while working. I believe it's on one of the standard USB audio classes so it should work.

Comment: Or, the F746 Discovery has way more RAM (8 megs)

Answer (score 1):

A proper answer this time, since you seemed interested in my comments.

If you are up to it, [AudioWeaver](https://dspconcepts.com/audio-weaver/st), the DSP code generation tool is free for ST Microelectronics microcontrollers.

How this works, is you create an effect/EQ/what you want in AudioWeaver and upload it to the memory integrated in the microcontroller. It then functions as a sound card. During development you use a second USB cable to upload the effect.

If you do not want to design a custom board, two not expensive kits are:

- [STM32F4DISCOVERY](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html), listed on ST's website for 20 USD
- [32F769IDISCOVERY](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32f769idiscovery.html) this one is 49 USD without display, 80 with, but has a bit more CPU power and a whopping 8 MB of RAM. Also the DAC looks a bit better.

Do keep in mind that the DACs used are not top class and the analog part is fully integrated into the DAC ICs, meaning that it will not be top quality (but you probably can't hear it).

Some other points raised in comments:

- AudioWeaver itself is Windows only, but all your settings are written to the board, so they are remembered through power cycles.
- I believe the board shows up as a standard sound card, meaning it should work with most systems - I certainly did not install any drivers on W10
- You only pay for the board
- You only use one "IDE" - Audio Weaver - to generate and upload the binary to the board
- If you wish to, you can generate a set of libraries which you can link to your own code (perhaps allowing for using the touch screen to control your effect?)
- If you like tinkering, a quick google shows that the F407 board is supported by Arduino IDE

There is a [video demonstration on YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcxPK96x7J0).

Comment: It's not what I had in mind, but better!  Thanks a lot for the video!  I really like the LabVIEW/signal-flow feel for signal processing instead of the direct procedural math in C that I would have done it in.  I might just have to go for that!  I'll let it sit a bit to see if someone else can beat it, but it's going to be pretty hard without an equivalent of AudioWeaver on a Pi.

Comment: Actually, the paid version of AudioWeaver supports the Pi itself from what I saw.

Comment: Where did you find that?  I'm coming up empty.  I found the paid version just fine, but I don't see the Pi mentioned.

Comment: https://dspconcepts.com/forums/audio-weaver-general/89-faq-which-development-boards-are-supported-audio-weaver

Comment: Ah!  Okay, I did see that, but I interpreted it as using the Pi as the dedicated DSP, while AW still runs on Windows to configure it.

Comment: @AaronD Yeah, that's what I meant :P you might be glad to know that programming and audio use separate USB connectors.

Comment: That the Pi is the DSP. Although I don't know about dedicated

Comment: My original problem is using the Pi as the DSP, and suspecting not enough spare cycles or buffers or whatever to keep up, and so I'm looking to offload that.  Ideally, the solution would be an external DSP with all the configuration tools running on the Pi, and only when needed to change something.  I guess the next best thing would be to separate the audio and control connections like you say the ST board does, so that a Windows laptop can be added temporarily to tweak it, but it would be better if it was all on the Pi except for the DSP itself.

Comment: @AaronD the Pi is very powerful. And I remember playing Warcraft 3 while listening to music on a 300 MHz Pentium 2. One issue I had with software EQs is that they allowed you to set steep curves while not being able to handle them and introducing artifacts.

Comment: That might be what I'm hearing.  Do you have a known example that I could listen to and compare?  I had to be pretty aggressive on the 10-band graphic to make my speakers sound even close to "right".  Looking at the shape though, I think a single biquad should be able to do that by itself.

Comment: @AaronD not really, it was back when WinAmp was my player of choice

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot recommend this one. I *finally* got around to buying a dev board, and the entire experience seems like corporate incompetence or at least non-communication between Marketing, IT, and Sales. The front page makes a big deal about being FREE for users of that brand of chip, but I had to complain to get that license to work. When I mentioned "false or deceptive advertising", *then* they turned it on for me. The salesperson that I talked to seemed rather stonewall-ish and apologized way too late about not realizing I had *that* license, when I had said up front what it was.

Comment: Once I was able to use it at all, I noticed a 1-hour "demo mode", after which it would stop processing anything and play an intermittent sine wave instead.  I complained about that too, got the same guy again, and he said that I had to buy a license because they didn't want people using their algorithms for free.  (*but the front page says...*)  Nevermind.  I thought about threatening legal action for their clearly false claims, but it's not worth the hassle.  Just don't buy.

Comment: [I'm looking at this now](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/118066/integrated-audio-dsp-with-free-tools/120697#120697), which [the HiFiBerry](https://www.hifiberry.com/shop/boards/hifiberry-dac-dsp/) is built around.

Comment: In keeping with my non-recommendation above, I feel obligated to retract my acceptance as well, for the people who don't read all the comments.  Sorry for the loss of rep.  If you know of something else, you're more than welcome to try again.  I'll keep the upvote though, as a "Thanks anyway for your efforts."

Comment: @AaronD I am sorry to hear that, especially after you actually went out of your way to buy that dev board. Hopefully you didn't buy one of the expensive ones. Might be they changed the terms since I wrote this answer, or they just don't care for hobbyists.

Comment: It was a cheap one.  $20 if I remember right, plus some other parts to share shipping, some related and some not.  They might have changed their terms, but if they did, they apparently forgot to update the website.